# Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, telerik

I am working on a WinForms application that uses Telerik WinForms. I took over maintenance application few months ago, and now I need to edit a form that uses these forms. But whenever I open the form it gives me this error. No matter if I try with debugging the code, trough Visual Studio, on the test server or on production. It's the same every time. Tried restarting the PC, tried re installing the Rad Controls, Visual Studio... And it's still the same. Tried it with colleges on another PCs, it works everywhere - except on my PC. And every other form that uses the same telerik gridview - works. Now I can't use nor edit the form. Anyone has an idea how to fix this, and what could be the problem?

PS: Here is the whole error log:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridException: Cannot find column with UniqueName 'Product'
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewColumnCollection.FindByUniqueName(String UniqueName)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewColumnCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at CustomerCare.Product.frmProducts.gvProducts_SizeChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.Telerik.WinControls.IComponentTreeHandler.CallSetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentLayoutElementTree.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleControl(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleChildControls(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.PerformAutoScale(Boolean includedBounds, Boolean excludedBounds)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.PerformNeededAutoScaleOnLayout()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnLayoutResuming(Boolean performLayout)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout(Boolean performLayout)
   at CustomerCare.Product.frmProducts.InitializeComponent()
   at CustomerCare.Product.frmProducts..ctor()
   at CustomerCare.frmMain.vertMeni_ItemClicked(Object sender, ItemClickedEventArgs e)
   at vbAccelerator.Components.ListBarControl.ListBar.OnItemClicked(ItemClickedEventArgs e)
   at vbAccelerator.Components.ListBarControl.ListBar.MouseSelectItem(ListBarItem item, MouseEventArgs e)
   at vbAccelerator.Components.ListBarControl.ListBar.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5477 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
CustomerCare
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5302.15719
    Win32 Version: 1.0.5302.15719
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/MakTel/Customer%20Care/CustomerCare.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5459 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
acclListBar
    Assembly Version: 1.0.1326.27884
    Win32 Version: 1.0.1326.27884
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/MakTel/Customer%20Care/acclListBar.DLL
----------------------------------------
Interop.EnCodecDLL
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/MakTel/Customer%20Care/Interop.EnCodecDLL.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5483 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.UI
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Telerik.WinControls.UI/6.0.0.0__5bb2a467cbec794e/Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Telerik.WinControls/6.0.0.0__5bb2a467cbec794e/Telerik.WinControls.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Services
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5483 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Services/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Design
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Design/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.Design
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing.Design/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
TelerikCommon
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/TelerikCommon/6.0.0.0__5bb2a467cbec794e/TelerikCommon.dll
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.GridView
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Telerik.WinControls.GridView/6.0.0.0__5bb2a467cbec794e/Telerik.WinControls.GridView.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Edit:

I removed the code from visual studio and managed to start the form in debug mode. Here is the code:

```
private void gvProducts_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region gvProducts_SizeChanged
            if (gvProducts.Size.Width > gvProductsSmallSize.Width)
            {
                gvProducts.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["Product"].Width = ((gvProducts.Size.Width - gvProductsSmallSize.Width) / 2) + 450;
                gvProducts.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["ProductGroupName"].Width = ((gvProducts.Size.Width - gvProductsSmallSize.Width) / 2) + 350;//this.Size.Width - frmProductSmallSize.Width + gvProducts.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["ProductGroupName"].Width;
            }
            else
            {
                gvProducts.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["Product"].Width = 450;
                gvProducts.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["ProductGroupName"].Width = 350;
                gvProducts.MasterGridViewTemplate.Columns["Status"].Width = 55;
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

I can edit the form, but won't be able to try it on production. Anyone can think of a workaround? I think it's windows issue or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct dll's on your machine?

Comment: @FeliceM yes, i do. I think it's some windows related issue. I removed part of the code directly in visual studio, and managed to start the form... But won't work on production.

Comment: Can you please specify which version of the suite the application uses and please confirm whether you are using the same version.

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking the `DesignMode` property and disabling the code which executes as a result of the various event handlers.

Otherwise, contact Telerik Support for help (or post on their forums).

Comment: I wrote, but no luck so far.. No one replied. I tried commenting the part of the code, and i managed to start the form in debug mode from Visual Studio.. The code is in the question above.